# Get Customer Address Details on Magento Backend

Tags: magento, backend

for my magento backend I need a link which is consiting of different customer informations.
So I want to get the specific Inforamions out of the backend but I don't know how.
I've already looked into the adminhtml/.../template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
and found the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_order->getCustomerName()) ?>
```

This is fine, but I need diffenent variables  for Customer Name, - Street, -Postcode, City to
build up a link like that:
www.domain.de/category&name=CustomerName&Street=CustomerStreet& .... 
How can I get these variables?
Thanks a lot for every answer!!

Comment: I believe I answered your question with sample code in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743362

Answer (score 0):

Customers can theoretically have many addresses. If you need the one supplied as the billing address with the order, use

```
$address = $order->getBillingAddress()
```

This will return an object of the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address` type, whose properties you can access via

```
$address->getCity()
$address->getStreet()
```

etc.

Otherwise you can fetch the customer's default billing address by calling

```
$address = $order->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress()
```

You can access to the entire customer address collection  as well:

```
$customerAddresses = $customer->getAddressesCollection()
```

Comment: i want customer billing address on totals.phtml file on sales order create page.