# Magento retrieve customer ID

Tags: php, magento

I've tried various methods to get the customerID but an empty value is stored in the variable. Please advise :)

Below remnants of things I've tried. The file is located in the root.

```
require_once '/home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php';
//Mage::app("default");

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/* if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      echo $customerData->getId();
 } */

 if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
} else {
    echo 'Not logged In';
}
```

Comment: also check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743362/how-to-convert-standalone-php-files-to-magentos-mvc/14780910#14780910 as I ramble on about getting customer info (which isn't exactly easy)

Comment: I've implemented these and get Call to a member function getId() on a non-object!

Comment: If you see my `foreach( $dealers as $id => $obj)` the id is a number and `$obj` is the customer object. Test for the result from your `$customers=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()` to ensure that `$customers` has something. I use `print_r($customers)` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require "/home/ab71714/public_html/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    print_r($session);
    $customerId = $session->getCustomer()->getId();
} else {
    echo 'Not logged In';
}
```

For more information:

http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/06/19/magento-get-customer-details-customer-id-name-email/

Comment: Kalpesh I've tried this and I get "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object". I realized that it wasn't getting past the if statement so I took the $customer= out of it and then the customer variable was a blank value. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1964129 i have edited the answer. can you please check it now?

Comment: Yeah Im getting not logged in but I am! Is file placement an issue?

Comment: do you want to get admin id (backend) or customer id (frontend)?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    echo $customerData->getId();
}
```