# Not getting customer collection in Magento block file?

Tags: magento

I am trying to get all the customers details according to their state wise for example collection of all customers from arizona.

Code:

```
$collection = array();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_region',$stateName)
    ->setOrder('billing_city', 'asc');
echo $stateName;   
echo $collection->getSelect();
print_r($collection); 
return $collection;
```

Now when i display the query and run it in sql it was working fine but the collection is not displaying anything.

Any help would be appreciated !!!!

Comment: where do you want to display these records ??

Comment: Are you including `app/Mage.php`? Like I talk about in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743362

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the collection:

```
->setOrder('billing_city', 'asc')->load();
```